# these data of yours

Tags: personal-pronouns, parentheses, personification, you-all

"These personal data of yours will be shared with authorized public institutions and organizations."
Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data as a plural noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126344/data-as-a-plural-noun) Best title, but itself closed as a duplicate. As have others.

Comment: It's grammatical. It doesn't sound very idiomatic. (Why not say *your personal data?*) It would be helpful to have more context.

Comment: I cannot say "your personal data" because I am talking about a specific group of personal data (internet traffic, phone number, etc.) not all of them.

Comment: @user351999 Simply remove the *of yours*.

Comment: There's also a strong precedent for using "data" in the singular to describe a collection of data. This precedent probably exists because it's not idiomatic at all to refer to a single datum in any context. For all intents and purposes, the word "datum" is defunct in modernity, and "data" can be and is used in the singular. Try, "This personal data will be shared [...]". Or, "These [streams of] personal data will be shared [...]".